# Python Stock Market Prediction code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, predict, stock

The Order sell condition: When ALL dataframe(5min, 15min, 60min and day) appear the sell signal( Signal ==-1) in the same day, return the date and closing price. I am able to generate order signal when 5min, 15min, 60min signals are matched (I didn't use the signal from day bar, as I cannot add it to the "dfall" dataframe. Need to solve this for better order signal)

```
for index, row in dfall.iterrows():
    order_buy_5 = dfall['Signal_5']==1
    order_buy_15 = dfall['Signal_15']==1
    order_buy_60 = dfall['Signal_60']==1
    order_buy_day = dfday['Signal']==1
    order_buy = (order_buy_5 & order_buy_15 & order_buy_60).item()

    if order_buy == True:
        print(dfday.index)
```

I then get this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-74a6a9101682> in <module>()
----> 1 for index, row in dfall.iterrows:
      2     order_buy_5 = dfall['Signal_5']==1
      3     order_buy_15 = dfall['Signal_15']==1
      4     order_buy_60 = dfall['Signal_60']==1
      5     order_buy_day = dfday['Signal']==1

TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `dataframe.iterrows()` (the brackets need to be there). You seemed to write it correctly in your snippet but looking at the traceback the executed code does not have the brackets.